# Shadow Dom and CSS3 :target selector

Tags: polymer, web-component

I should start off by saying that I don't really have an issue that I'm trying to work through. I just had an interesting thought about how Shadow Dom and the CSS3 `:target` selector might / should / currently do work together.

I know that HTML specification says that there should only ever be one element with a particular ID value in a valid HTML document. But when we start using webcomponents with shadow dom we could very easily find ourselves using multiple elements with the same ID. This is especially true when we use the same component multiple times in the same page. So the question that I have is this: what should happen to an element inside a shadow dom region that has an ID value which matches the current hash and which is styled with a `:target` rule?

For example, if I wrote a webcomponent (my-element) that contained

```
<style>
#debug {display:none}
#debug:target { display:block; background-color:yellow; border 2px solid red; }
</style>
<div id="debug">some debug data</div>
```

What should happen to all the instance of my-element that I put on a page and navigated to #debug on?  Should the debug element in each component show? Should none of them show? Should only the first element's debug div show (the same one I'd expect the browser to try and navigate to)?

My opinion is that if the page does not have an element with an `ID=debug` value that no scrolling navigation should appear on the page. As shadow dom is isolated from the rest of the page's styles the browser shouldn't try to navigate to such an element nested in shadow dom.  Each my-element instance should be able to see the current page's URL though and should apply any matching :target rules, such that each my-elements' debug div should be visible.

If this were the case it would make for some interesting possibilities for sharing page state across all components, such as the debug example above. However, I doubt that is how Chrome is currently implementing things. And I'm pretty sure this Shadow Dom polyfill isn't going to handle things correctly as it basically shoehorns everything into the page's Dom tree and that would break the html specification.

Just curious if anyone has an answer for how this should work and how it works today...

(edited from my pc to add formatting... hard to do from my phone)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can see the shadow DOM like a nested document. CSS can't address elements inside the shadow DOM from the outside (previously existing shadow piercing CSS selectors were deprecated). 
This also encapsulates ids and therefore multiple components that contain elements with an id won't cause collisions or duplicates.

If you have the CSS with the `:target` selector inside a components style, it should be able to address the element with the matching id, otherwise it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

> So the question that I have is this: what should happen to an element
> inside a shadow dom region that has an ID value which matches the
> current hash and which is styled with a :target rule?

Adding to Günter Zöchbauer above [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42502380/6582782) an alternative is to use the [Custom Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry) object when the style is encapsulated, if the style is global it will work just fine. Use the [define](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define) method to create a custom component as shown in the the docs. This will not encapsulate your elements so be aware that your styles can be shared across files.

So instead of doing this:

```js
const shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
shadow.appendChild(pTag)
```

Use this:

```js
this.appendChild(pTag);
```

*both previous examples suppose you're in a [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=HTMLElement) class or a class that inherits it.*